# Connecting iOS with Azure Cloud

Tags: ios, azure

I'm sorry, I don't get this Azure Cloud thing working for iOS.
Has anyone had experiences with this so far? I don't get any useful results in google...

Up to now I downloaded the Azure Toolkit for iOS on https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-toolkit-ios and didn't really get it working. On every video/tutorial I found, they referenced to another github site which is now 404 error. I finally found the referenced project on another link but didn't get this working for me either.

For the Azure Toolkit on https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-toolkit-ios I didn't find where to put my namespace, user and key (so I got an error like "hostname not found").

For the "other" (older version?) Toolkit there are some "directory not found" errors while building.

Any help? I don't believe that there is nobody out there having connected iOS with Azure successfully!

Comment: I am using Azure with web services. Do you really need direct access to the Azure data base?

Comment: hm, I don't know exactly what you mean. I don't need to connect with SQL Azure but the service bus to send xml data to or from the cloud.

Comment: I am doing that with services. The web service gives me data when I load a particular url. And I can post date via httppost. I did not write the web service, so I can't help you about that. But I did not include any third party code into my project.

Comment: ok, maybe it's better to work with an additional web service which manages requests with the azure cloud... thanks very much!

Comment: Please check http://codeisclean.blogspot.in/ I have written a post in there and you can download the sample code also. If you still hit a wall, I shall help you.

Comment: Any buddy has any idea that Azure supports 'real live stream', or we need to play recorded file from the server ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version from Github, you should open the watoolkitios-samples.xcodeproj in Xcode. Then, I think the README.md is a bit out of date, you need to open watoolkitios-samples.plist in the "Supporting Files" folder in order to configure the client application. You have a number of configuration types to choose from, the simplest is "Direct", although probably not recommended for production use.

This library offers a rather spohisticated set of Web Services that you can call directly from the iOS client. I would try it out before starting building services from scratch!