# Windows Azure Toolkit displays Parser error in iOS

Tags: ios, windows, azure

I tried with the below code snippet taken from the website after replacing with my namespace and realm. But when i try to run the application, I am receiving the parser error like

**Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found**

```
WACloudAccessControlClient *acsClient =
  [WACloudAccessControlClient
          accessControlClientForNamespace:@“iostest-walkthrough”
                                    realm:@“uri:wazmobiletoolkit”];

 [acsClient showInViewController:self
                     allowsClose:NO
           withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL authenticated)
 {
    if (!authenticated) {
        NSLog(@"Error authenticating");
    } else {
        WACloudAccessToken *token = [WACloudAccessControlClient sharedToken];
        NSString *securityToken = [token securityToken];
    }
  }];
```

I am not able to understand the issue clearly.

Please guide me with example. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165778/connecting-ios-with-azure-cloud/11304825#11304825

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the samples here:

https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-ios

You can also look at this for getting started:

http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/05/windows-azure-toolkit-for-ios/

My guess is that you didn't #import something you need.